# VS2012 with Xamarin 3, frezes when adding MvvmCross 3.1.1 nuget package to android project

Tags: visual-studio-2012, xamarin, mvvmcross, nuget-package

I've recently upgraded the Xamarin to the new version (Xamarin 3).
After this update, everytime I try to add the MvvmCross 3.1.1 nuget package to an android project, the VS2012 freezes (In the dialog window when he's trying to resolve and add the references).

Can this be an issue with the nuget package? 
I haven't seen anyone complain about this, so I'm more inclined to say that there may be something wrong in my xamarin instalation, but first I would like to know if anyone else had this problem...

Comment: I had a similar problem with a Xamarin update. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK Tools and Android SDK Build Tools installed. The reason it hangs is that MvvmCross adss resources to your project and if you don't have the correct resource compiler from the SDK, it fails and hangs.

Comment: Thank you!
In fact I didn't had the latest API installed. I updated it via SDK Manager and the problem was solved!
Please, feel free to post it as an answer so that I can upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem with a Xamarin update. Make sure you have the latest Android SDK Tools and Android SDK Build Tools installed. The reason it hangs is that MvvmCross adds resources to your project and if you don't have the correct resource compiler from the SDK, it fails and hangs.